# Locked myself out of Google Compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I ran into an issue when I mistakenly changed my quotum for Google Compute engine queries per 100 seconds per user to 0.

I thought 0 would mean 'unlimited' but apparently it's really 0. Making this worse: The quota page itself falls under the Google Compute Engine query API so I can't access that at all.

It feels like I just bricked my entire project but I hope there is a way around this.

I only have a bronze service account, so can't really go to Google with this.

Comment: Normally, when you try to set any of the API quota to "0", you should see a message similar to this. "You're reducing a quota limit by more than 10%, which can impact existing activities. Are you sure you want to continue?" Did you check the box to confirm this? Also, did you try to increase the number back by visiting   the quota page. Ex. https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=compute.googleapis.com&project=[PROJECTID] and then click on the pencil to edit the number; as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rsrC.png)

Comment: Yeah, saw all that and (realizing it now) quite stupidly clicked past it. Like I said, the quota page is not accessible, since it is apparently part of the API, which seems a bit stupid on Google's end.

Comment: I tried and was unable to reproduce similar behavior. Hence, I would suggest that you notify Google using the following [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901). This will create a private issue that only you and Googlers will have access to. You should include the Google Cloud Project Number that you are having issues with and also add the ServerFault question that prompted opening this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For whom who is facing similar issues in 2021 I post this answer to make it more visible.

I tried to reproduce this issue and I wasn't able to do it. As it was already mentioned by @arp-sunny in the comment section, this situation looks like an issue on Google Cloud side. In such cases you can reach out to [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) or/and follow the documentation [Report issues and request features with issue trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and file an issue report:

> Google reviews every new issue report submitted by users. Sometimes one of our staff will ask for clarification or followup. Once we're able to replicate the issue, we'll tell you that it's been forwarded to the appropriate team.
>
> Depending on the circumstances, we may be able to provide periodic updates while an issue is being looked at, but usually we cannot provide too many specifics about the exact cause of an issue, or when it will be fixed.
>
> When we've fixed an issue in production, we'll indicate this and then we'll close the issue.

In addition to that, whenever you see any issues with Google Cloud Platform you can check status of it at [this dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/).